# Left outer join and multiple counts SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

How would this query using an inner join, left outer join, group by and two counts be converted to linq?

```
SELECT
    c.EndowmentID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT f.CriterionID) AS RequiredCriteria,
    COUNT(r.ChoiceID) AS Response
FROM
    Criteria c
INNER JOIN
    Filters f
ON
    c.ID = f.CriterionID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Responses r
ON
    f.ChoiceID = r.ChoiceID
WHERE
    f.IsRequirement = 1
GROUP BY
    c.EndowmentID;
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
            var result =
                from c in context.Criteria
                join f in context.Filters on c.ID equals f.CriterionID
                join r in context.Responses on f.ChoiceID equals r.ChoiceID into resfil
                from rf in resfil.DefaultIfEmpty()
                group rf by c.EndowmentID into grouped
                select new 
                {
                    EndowmentID = grouped.Key,
                    Requirements = grouped.Count(t=>t.CriterionID),
                    Response = grouped.Count(t=>t.ChoiceID)
                };
```

Comment: What have you tried? I'll give you a hint, you use `Where`, `GroupBy`, `Select`, and two `Join`'s. All of that translates very directly into LINQ.

Comment: please show us what you have so far -- we need to see that you've put some effort into it, and see where exactly you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `group` using an anonymous class. This will allow you to access all your tables in your `select` statement

```
group new { c, f, rf } by c.EndowmentID into grouped
```

---

SQL: `COUNT(DISTINCT f.CriterionID) AS RequiredCriteria,`

This can be written by first selecting the `f.CriterionID` column, `Distinct()`, `Count()`

```
RequiredCriteria = grouped.Select(x => x.f.CriterionID).Distinct().Count()
```

---

SQL: `COUNT(r.ChoiceID)`

```
Response = grouped.Select(x => x.rf.ChoiceID).Count()
```